# How to get the fields of go struct

Tags: interface, struct, go

Lets say we have a `User` type

```
type User struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    ...
}
```

I need a function that returns `[]string` with the field names in it `[FirstName, LastName, ...]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using reflection (via the [reflect](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByNameFunc) package):

```
instance := struct{Foo string; Bar int }{"foo", 2}

v := reflect.ValueOf(instance)

names := make([]string, 0, v.NumField())

v.FieldByNameFunc(func(fieldName string) bool{
    names = append(names, fieldName)
    return false
})
```

Live example on [play](http://play.golang.org/p/xxzvP4v4I0).